# using .trim() with jquery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, trim

I am using jQuery Live Form Validation from [GeekTantra](http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-live-form-validation/)

The validation is called by ID. Here is the code I use to set the options for a field that is a 2 digit number less than 50:

```
jQuery("#ValidNumber2Digits50").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL.length <= 2 && !isNaN(VAL) && VAL < 50) return true; else return false;",
        message: "Please enter a 2 digit number less than 50"
    });
```

The only problem is that it counts white spaces in the length. S0...

```
_4 ==> good data 
4_==> good data
_9_ ==> bad data 
_ _2 ==> bad data
```

I tried:

```
if (VAL.trim.length <= 2 && !isNaN(VAL) && VAL < 50) return true; else return false;
```

which did not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [tag:jquery-validate] tag is only for the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please be more mindful when tagging.

Answer (score 2):

[`trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) is a function - try using `$.trim(VAL).length` instead.

Comment: @iknowkungfoo Thanks. It works, the only problem is that if I leave the field blank, it throws an error. The field is NOT required. Any thoughts?